# Sencha Touch 2: recursive message boxes

Tags: javascript, recursion, popup, sencha-touch-2, message

There are two popups. The second one appears instead of the first one if `showAlert(text)` returns true (please see the working code below).

How to modify it the way to show the first message back all the time upon OK of the second message?

As result, it looks like:

```
1. Please enter your email. 
2. If email is correct, then go to step 5.
3. Please, fix your email. Click OK.
4. Go to step 1.
5. Success. Finished.
```

My working code is below.

```
Ext.Msg.prompt(
    'My Title', //The title bar text 
    'This is the first message', //The message box body text
    function (btn, text) {
       if (btn == 'ok') {
          if (showAlert(text)) {
              Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Please, fix it');//to show first message upon OK button
           } else {
                //do something useful
           }
       }
    },
    //some more params
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your call a function, and call that function as the callback if the email is not valid:

```
function showPrompt() {
    Ext.Msg.prompt(
        'My Title', //The title bar text 
        'This is the first message', //The message box body text
        function (btn, text) {
            if (btn == 'ok') {
                if (showAlert(text)) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Please, fix it', showPrompt);
                } else {
                    //do something useful
                }
            }
        },
        //some more params
    );
}
```